# Metal sampler - Proper addressing mode when filtering

Tags: textures, metal, sampling

I am doing image registration using a Metal sampler. For every fragment, I sample the source texture using the transformed coordinates of the fragment. Initially, the filtering was set to "nearest" (and addressing mode to "clamp_to_zero"), and everything was good. However, after I changed the filtering to "linear", I noticed that the first border rows and columns were not rendered correctly. After some testing, I realized (and I might be wrong) that when I sample the texture for values < 0.5 (in the case of the first row or column, for example), the sampler interpolates using the first texel and the next texel, which is actually outside the texture. Since the addressing mode was set to "clamp_to_zero", interpolation was done using the first texel and zero. Setting the addressing mode to "clamp_to_edge" seemed to fix the problem since interpolation was now done between the first texel and a copy of itself, which returns the value of the first texel (same as using "nearest").

However, I am not sure if the problem is truly fixed or simply greatly attenuated. Maybe using "mirrored_repeat" would be better? Also, what about when using bicubic filtering, which (I think) uses more than just the next texel?